# Compute $\iint\limits_R\frac{y}{x+y^2}dA$ where $R=[0,1]\times[1,2]$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Compute $\displaystyle\iint\limits_R\frac{y}{x+y^2}dA$ where $R=[0,1]\times[1,2]$

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_1^2\frac{y}{x+y^2}dydx=\int_0^1\int_1^2y(x+y^2)^{-1}dydx$

How do I integrate the denominator if the superscript is $-1$?

Hints are appreciated!

Comment: Which subscript should be -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1**: notice that $\frac{d}{dy}(x+y^2) = 2y$ so $\int y/(x+y^2) \, dy = (\ln{|x+y^2|})/2$.

**Hint 2**: you may also want to take advantage of [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) and write your integral as follows:

$$I = \int^2_1 \int^1_0 f(x,y) \, dxdy,$$

so it becomes a little bit easier.